# UITableView only displays some images

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView that displays images next in each row. The problem I have is that it only displays the images for the first three rows, and the it won't show in the rest. In order to test, from the second image i have set it to display exactly the same (so only the first is different).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }
    // Configure the cell...

    cell.textLabel.text = [booklist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"(opt) We can add more info here";
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:MyImagePath];

    //Arrow 
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell; }
```

Can anyone help, please?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your numberOfRowsInSection set to 3 by any chance??

Comment: No, it's set to [booklist count]. In fact all the cell are displayed with the correct data and they push to the detailed view correctly. The only problem is that the image is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there was some issue with the database data where I stored the file names. I repopulated it (with the same data!) and now it's working fine.

Can't understand why, but it's working.